# MySQL Get Parent With Child Rows Together

Tags: mysql

i have searched for questions like this and although many are similars, are not answering exact my questions and queries not work.

Assuming we have the following table

```
id     category_name     parent_id
------------------------------------
1      test              0
2      test1             0
3      new_cat           1
4      new_catx          2
5      cat5              1
```

I want an sql query where the output will be like this

```
id     category_name     parent_id
------------------------------------
1      test              0
3      new_cat           1
5      cat5              1
2      test1             0
4      new_catx          2
```

In sort the output query is sorted based on parent_id. The `parent_id = 0` is the root category, then child are following, and then again another parent with it's child. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for a 1-level tree, i.e. for a tree containing only parents and their children:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY CONCAT(IF(parent_id=0, '', parent_id), id)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4e1b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use a mapping table for this, to make your solution cleanly scalable. Change your original table struct to

```
id    category_name
---------------------
1     test
2     test1
3     new_cat
4     new_catx
5     cat5
```

...and have a parent mapping table, like so:

```
id    parent_id
---------------------
3     1
4     2
5     1
```

Then you would simply modify Giorgos Betsos' excellent query to read:

```
select t.id, t.category_name, p.parent_id
from testtable t left outer join parents p
    on t.id = p.id
ORDER BY CONCAT(IF(p.parent_id is null, '', p.parent_id), t.id);
```